How to remove rows in a matrix with a certain criteria
I have a gene expression matrix consisting of  7,219 columns and 6,817 rows. I wish to remove the rows that have a low variability. E.g the rows such that the max\min value in that row is <= 5, as well as the rows where the max - min <=500. I do not know the index for a max value of a row, only that of the whole matrix. Should I use an for or if loop? Or is there an easier method? Thank you
I have looked online for any solutions but only found ways to exclude rows when elements are certain values, not where there is an inequality involving multiple elements as the criteria.
